# TinyMCE4 icons not displayed when web font downloading disabled

Tags: tinymce, webfonts

Our product is used by many corporate and government bodies.
Many of them are only allowed use IE and have security policies applied to their IE which they are not allowed adjust.

One such setting is the disabling of downloading web fonts.

[image]

We have work around in place to check if the font can be downloaded.
If not, we replace all `<i>` on the page with `<img>`.

```
var haveFont = detectFontIcons();

//Iterate over each icon on the page and replace if necessary
if (!haveFont)
    $('[class^="mce-i-"]').each( function(e) {
        console.log("Found element = ", this);

        // Replace all <i></i> with <img>
        ....

    }
}
```

This works fine for all our custom Html.

**The Problem:**
For some reason it will not work for `tinyMCE <i>` tags.
I have adjusted the class prefeix to allow for the TinyMCE `'mce-i-'`.
It finds no elements in the DOM with `'mce-i'` even though I can see them using firebug.

I have even set a timeout on the call to do this check, incase it was an issue with the DOM not been fully rendered yet. No luck.

**Questions:**
1: Any ideas on why no TinyMCE elements are not been found?
2: How can I update tinyMCE to use images directly instead of web fonts?

Thanks

Comment: what about having the necessary fonts shipped out by you or placed inside a local accessible directory for custom files like css and fonts?

Answer (score 1):

I can't take credit for this, but I found a font-free, custom skin that replaces the fonts with images.  I added the skin, updated my init method and it appears to work as I'd hoped.

It can be found here:
 - https://pollyshaw.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/a-font-free-skin-for-tinymce-version-4/
 - https://bitbucket.org/pollyshaw1/tinymce-4-lightgray-no-fonts-skin